# Set a loop through button

Tags: java

I want to set a loop when I push the button and quit from it when I release the button...

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    try {
        mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(mEditSend.getText().toString().getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps create a `private class` that `implements Runnable` containing your loop, launch it when the button is clicked and stop it when the button is released.

Comment: What is solution when i want hold button and get into loop?